# passing value from ajax call to a form submit

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a form, html elements get added to it via ajax calls, and I want to be able to pass the values of the added html elements to the form submit. Details:

I have a simple form_for:

```
<%= form_tag(:controller => "operations", :action => "new") do %>
<%= select_tag "operation", options_for_select(%w{a s m d} )%>
```

depending on a user's action on the select tag, I do

```
$.get(url, params,function(response){
}, 'script')});
```

The ajax call returns an html radio_button_tag  i.e. the url called has something like:

```
<div class="modifer">
<%= radio_button_tag elid, 'no' %>
</div>
```

The user can now select the radio button, and I want to pass this value as part of the form submit. I really don't understand how to pass the value of the radio_button_tag (elid) as part of the form submit.

Would appreciate some clarification on this

Comment: Are you inserting the .modifier div into the form? If so, it will be submitted with the form.

Comment: Thank you! your comment helped me figure out the problem. The .modifier div was being appended to a div that was not in the form. I fixed that and it is now working fine.

Comment: Great! I'll add it as answer answer so you can mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you inserting the .modifier div into the form? If so, it will be submitted with the form.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all of the form elements have a `name` attribute you can serialize the whole form using `$('#formID').serialize()`

API reference: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

You would then submit with ajax:

```
$.post( '/path/to/server/', $('#formID').serialize(), function ( response){
   /* do something with response if needed*/
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I learnt something new. However, my problem was resolved by investigating the comment above